# How can I dynamically resize a grid of divs to fill (but not exceed) the dimensions of a container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to complete an assignment for "The Odin Project." The goal is to create an etch-a-sketch-like webpage. I've gotten decently far, but I've been stuck trying to dynamically resize a grid of divs.

I have a container div that I set to 500x500px. However nothing I've tried has the container divs filling up the space appropriately. I feel that I'm missing something trivial in the CSS, but can't figure out what.

CSS:

```
 .outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}

#gridtable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.outtable {
    background: #CCC;
    min-height: 1%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 1%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.newcolor {
    background: blue;
    min-height: 1%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 1%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o4poarey/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set your table elements to fill the available width as well (i.e. 100%) at the moment they default to the minimum space needed (this is table defaults)

```
.outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
   position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gridtable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

table, tbody, tr, td{
    width: 100%;  

}
.intable{display: flex; }
.intable td{}
.outtable{
    background: #CCC;
    min-height: 1%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.newcolor {
    background: blue;
    min-height: 1%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o4poarey/6/

Comment: Thank you for responding! I think your post is pointing in the right direction. However the table divs are still not filling the container div completely (e.g. if 2 divs, each one is 250x250; if 20 divs, each one is 25x25, etc).

Comment: change it, i didnt count the elements, so if there are 20 = 100/20=5, `.intable td{width:5%}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use 100% not px

```
<...width="100%" height="100%"...>
```

instead of

```
<...width="100px" height="100px"...>
```

Also put in a table and set the table to 100%

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><...width="100%" height="100%"...></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```